# How to write a builder object to an output stream object in Cap'n Proto in C++ instead of a file?

Tags: c++11, capnproto

I am creating a CAP'N PROTO  builder object like this:

```
::capnp::MallocMessageBuilder message;
InjectorRequestMsg::Builder injectorRequestMsg = message.initRoot<InjectorRequestMsg>();
```

/*Then setting all data members of injectorRequestMsg*/
After that I am trying to write the object to a file like this:

```
writePackedMessageToFd(fd, message);
```

This works perfectly.
But, I am not able to figure out how to write this object to an output stream object using the method:

```
void writePackedMessage(kj::BufferedOutputStream& output, MessageBuilder& builder);
```

Actually, I am having issues with creating a **kj::BufferedOutputStream** object.
Any idea or a simple example on this regard will be greatly helpful for me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something similar. I needed to output my data to a memory space. I was able to do so by doing:

```
kj::VectorOutputStream stream;
::capnp::writePackedMessage(stream, message);
/* then use stream.getArray() to get access to the data */
```